# Soldering battery lips

Tags: batteries, soldering

I'm thinking of buying [this battery](http://www.robotshop.com/li-ion-rechargeable-battery-800mah.html):

[image]

As you can see, there are no solder lips. I'd like to add them myself, but don't know if that's a good idea. Is it possible to solder lips on a battery yourself? What equipment would I need? Are there any safety issues that I should be aware of, and how can I make this secure?

Comment: Usually these things aren't soldered but use a spot weld. I've soldered them before, but never turned out very nice looking. Also resistance for a spot weld is much lower than a (poor) soldering

Comment: @jippie I'm afraid I don't have the equipment to spot-weld. Is it okay to solder it, or is it strongly discouraged?

Comment: @CamilStaps You can spot-weld using a home-made capacitive discharge set-up. Works well after you figure out how to make it work at all :-) That is what is used with aluminium or chrome-plated metals for instance, which aren't very solder friendly.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh hmm, isn't that dangerous?

Comment: @CamilStaps Nope. We're talking capacitor discharge of a tiny actual amount of stored joules, sourced off a 9 volt battery or 4 AAs. At least, that is what I scraped together  the last time I needed it.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh interesting. Do you have a link to such a project?

Comment: @CamilStaps I just have a clutter of wires, a few 2n3055 BJTs, some MOSFETs, 6 or 7 100 Volt electrolytic caps, a push-button, and some other junk in an undecipherable deadbug-style circuit in my "legacy junk" boxes :-) However, I am sure there are a few such projects out there. Come to think of it, I don't even remember what the 3055s were for in that circuit of mine.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh I'm not experienced in this field. What should I look for? Or can you find me a reliable project?

Comment: http://zeva.com.au/Projects/SpotWelder/ ... and now, come to [Chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15/electrical-engineering) if you want to to discuss this further!

Comment: @AnindoGhosh no, that link is just perfect! Thank you :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

- Often the metal at the contacts will have a thin chrome plating. Scrape that with some fine sandpaper, then flux and solder.
- However, heat is a risk, and if those batteries did not come with solder tabs, then soldering wires on would most likely violate warranties besides possibly exploding or just degrading.
- If you must solder, use the highest solder iron temperature, so that the soldering is a really quick job.
- Standard AA spring-loaded battery cases are pretty inexpensive, that would be my choice for batteries like the one indicated. An option would be to take the "negative side" spring off two cases, and use one at each end, replacing the flat metal contact typically found on the positive side.

Answer (score 6):

Soldering batteries is a bad idea.  They can easily be damaged from the heat.  The battery you show is intended for a battery holder.  Either use a holder, or get a battery with solder tabs.

If you do add solder tabs yourself, use spot welding.  This uses heat too, but the total energy is low since it's so quick.  Make sure to set up the equipment so that the spot welding current pulse does not go thru the battery.